# Is there a Ruby client for the US National Weather Service data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, weather, weather-api

The only US weather data that is available free for commercial use is the [US National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/). I'd like to use it. Is there a Ruby/Rails library for accessing it?

Perl would also be helpful. They provide a [Perl example](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/ndfdXML.tar). I'd use it as a guide for writing the Ruby version.

Comment: The US Nat Weather Svc REST api for the forecast data: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/rest.php Here's REST api for current observations: http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NWS provides a [RESTful web service](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/rest.php) in addition to the SOAP service, but if your needs are simple, consider the [outoftime-noaa](http://github.com/outoftime/noaa) gem on github.  It provides a straightforward interface for obtaining forecast and current conditions data.

(Be warned that one of its dependencies is not yet compatible with Ruby 1.9.)

Comment: This looks great, thank you. I think I'll add a simple memcache layer above it since NWS only updates data every 60 min.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Perl [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) module called [`Weather-NWS`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Weather-NWS/) which uses the [NDFD](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/).

Answer (score 2):

The [NDFD](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/) is a SOAP-based web service. Just use a Ruby SOAP client to send it the right information and handle the response. Did you have a question about using SOAP from Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're wanting to do.

If you just want a widget for a location or two the SOAP interface is fine.

If you want a large amount of data (or many locations) then NOAA wants you to download the raw [grib2](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/NDFD_GRIB2Decoder/) data (updated) hourly. A simple batch job works for that.